# How can I loop my TTS program to say open until I close it?

Tags: loops, vbscript, text-to-speech

I am currently working on a simple VBScript text-to-speech program for fun, but I am having a little bit of trouble with the last line of code. Whenever I try to open it, a window pops up saying that a loop is expected on line 7. I was going to modify the last line a bit, but now I can't remember what I need there. Right now, I do not have a "line 7", and I couldn't find any help elsewhere. The code so far is:

```
Dim message, sapi
Set sapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
Do
    message = InputBox("Speech Bot. Version 1.5")

    If message <> "" Then sapi.Speak message
```

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57ykwk20.aspx). Your `Do` loop is missing the `Loop` keyword marking the end of the loop.

Comment: Download the docs here http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe